# Cointegration of a VAR(1) process

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cointegration, vector-autoregression

I am using a Johansen procedure to test for cointegration a vectorial 4-dim vector (timeserie).

First I tested for differential stationarity of each individual vector, all of those have a unit root so we are good there.

Then I have to find the optimal number of lags as to test for cointegration using Johansen, we assume that the underlying process is a `VAR` process. And that's where the problem occur, I usually find `K=1` (`K` minimizes several information criterias).

I use the package `urca` and the function `ca.jo` to run the `trace` and `eigen` tests, but `ca.jo` only allows `K>1` (which makes sense because of the model).

What does this `K=1` means ? I add that If I take `K=2` both Johansen tests comes back significant and the process indeed looks cointegrated...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, what K=1 means? From the text I understand that you know what lag order is. If you specify what want to know, I'll see if I can help you.

Comment: I am saying that `K=1` is the number of lags that minimizes all the information criterias, as such it is the value I should use to parametrize my VAR process. `ca.jo` do not allow to specify `K=1` as a value for parameter `K`. Basically I am not sure what I should deduce from finding `1` for `K`, Am I clearer ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be the lag selection that gives the least information loss (AIC), but it doesn't necessarily mean that the true process only regress on only the first lag. Try to choose the second best K according to your information criteria. It is often found that the lag length suggested by information criteria isn't a very good fit.